# Redis CRDB Eviction Policy

Tags: caching, redis, spring-data-redis

I have read in the redis documentation that caching eviction policy for CRDB should be set to **No Eviction** .

"Note: Geo-Distributed CRDBs always operate in noeviction mode."

https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/administering/database-operations/eviction-policy/

Reasoning for that is the garbage collection might cause inconsistencies as both the data center will have bidirectional synch. 
I am not getting this point, can someone explain by giving a real world problem that might occur if suppose we have cache eviction policy LRU .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is outdated and irrelevant, and has a link to an already updated doc which makes this Q&A even more confusing.

Comment: Redis Enterprise CRDB supports eviction

Answer (score -1):

I got to know after doing some research that it is often a trouble to handle eviction when we have active replication. For example if one of the master runs out of memory and cache is trying to evict the keys to make some room for latest data, what might happen is - it will delete those keys from the other master even if there are no memory issues there. So until and unless there is really a good way to handle this ,eviction is not supported.